# Blank cell contains a value when code is executed

Tags: excel, vba

I’m using a userform with 12 listboxes (numbered 2-13).  Each list box could contain 0-8 items assigned by user from main listbox1.  I run the following code to output the content of each list box (12 boxes) to sheet “Tray” when a button is pressed.

Each listbox is then output into corresponding columns of each tray from columns B-M.  Listbox2 fills column 1 of each tray and so on.  A maximum of 4 trays can be filled.  The code checks the 1st well of each tray and if it contains a value it assumes the tray is full & begins filling the next tray.

Problem: If the first tray contains a blank column(listbox) and the second tray contains values in the same listbox, the code will fill blank column of the frist tray with values that should be in the second tray.  Please see pictures below and updated code below:

Listboxes 2,3 and 4 for Tray 1 (note listbox3 is empty)

[image]

Listboxes 2,3 and 4 for tray 2 (note listbox3 has data)

[image]

Code ran two times: Listbox3 from tray2 appears in tray1 (erroneously!!!)

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

```
Sub Worklist()
'
Dim Var, VarName As Variant
Dim i, DblDashPos, FirstPeriodPos, lngColNum, lngRowNum As Long
Dim item As ListBox

Const cstrNames As String = "Listbox2,Listbox3,Listbox4,Listbox5,Listbox6,Listbox7,Listbox8,Listbox9,Listbox10,Listbox11,Listbox12,Listbox13"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lngColNum = 2

For Each VarName In Split(cstrNames, ",")


    If UserForm2.Controls(VarName).ListIndex <> -1 Then 'if listbox is not blank

        If Sheets("Tray").Cells(4, lngColNum).Value = 0 Then
        'checks if value in row 3 column "lngColNum" is empty
            lngRowNum = 4
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tray").Range("C2").Value = UserForm2.TextBox1.Value

        ElseIf Sheets("Tray").Cells(15, lngColNum).Value = 0 Then 'checks if value in row 14 column "lngColNum" is empty

            lngRowNum = 15

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tray").Range("C13").Value = UserForm2.TextBox1.Value

        ElseIf Sheets("Tray").Cells(26, lngColNum).Value = 0 Then 'checks if value in row 14 column "lngColNum" is empty

            lngRowNum = 26

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tray").Range("C24").Value = UserForm2.TextBox1.Value

        Else 'otherwise assumes tray starts in row 5, column "lngColNum"

            lngRowNum = 37
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tray").Range("C35").Value = UserForm2.TextBox1.Value

        End If


        For i = 0 To UserForm2.Controls(VarName).ListCount - 1
            Var = UserForm2.Controls(VarName).List(i)

            DblDashPos = InStr(1, Var, "--")
            FirstPeriodPos = InStr(1, Var, ".")
            Sheets("Tray").Select
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRowNum, lngColNum) = Left(Var, DblDashPos - 1) & Right(Var, Len(Var) - FirstPeriodPos + 1)

            lngRowNum = lngRowNum + 1
        Next i

    End If


    lngColNum = lngColNum + 1

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: try to change this line: `If Len(Cells(3, lngColNum).Value) = 0 Then` to If `Cells(3, lngColNum).Value = "" Then` .

Comment: it still thinks there is something in B3 and B14 (although they are clearly blank) and outputs in Tray3 (first row of that tray is 25) It is so strange because a value it debug.prints in B14 is not even in any of the listboxes.

Comment: try to use your sheet name like `sheets("thesheetname").Cells(3, lngColNum).Value`

Comment: your suggestion helped but I'm still having problems. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only testing the column that corresponds to the ListBox to see if the cell is empty.  If you want to test that *all* of the columns in a "tray" are empty, you need to test once for the entire sheet.  Something like this (untested because I'm too lazy to rebuild your form):

```
Private Function FindFirstUnusedRow(sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim testColumn As Long, testRow As Long
    Dim used As Boolean

    For testRow = 4 To 37 Step 11
        used = False
        For testColumn = 2 To 13
            If IsEmpty(sheet.Cells(testRow, testColumn)) = False Then
                used = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next testColumn
        If used = False Then
            FindFirstUnusedRow = testRow
            Exit For
        End If
    Next testRow
End Function
```

Then in your code, call it before your loop:

```
Sub Worklist()
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim i As Long, dashPos As Long, periodPos As Long, colNum As Long
    Dim rowNum As Long, Dim sheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tray")
    rowNum = FindFirstUnusedRow(sheet)

    If rowNum = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "All trays full."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim current As ListBox
    For colNum = 2 To 13
        Set current = UserForm2.Controls("Listbox" & colNum)
        If current.ListIndex <> -1 Then 'if listbox is not blank
            sheet.Cells(rowNum - 2, colNum).Value = UserForm2.TextBox1.Value
            For i = 0 To current.ListCount - 1
                var = current.List(i)
                dashPos = InStr(1, var, "--")
                periodPos = InStr(1, var, ".")
                sheet.Cells(rowNum + i, colNum) = Left$(var, dashPos - 1) & _
                                    Right$(var, Len(var) - periodPos + 1)
            Next i
        End If
    Next colNum
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

A couple other notes:  You can ditch the `Sheets("Tray").Select` line entirely - you never use the selection object.  Same thing with the mixed references to `ActiveSheet` and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tray")`.  Grab a reference and use it.

Also, these lines don't do what you think they do:

```
Dim Var, VarName As Variant
Dim i, DblDashPos, FirstPeriodPos, lngColNum, lngRowNum As Long
```

Of all the variables you declare, *everything* is a `Variant` except `lngRowNum`.  If you want to combine declarations on one line like that, you still need to specify a type **for each variable**, or they'll default to `Variant`.  See the example code above.

Comment: I get type mismatch here `Set current = UserForm2.Controls("Listbox" & colNum)` thanks

Comment: @user3781528 - I can't replicate the error - it does the same thing as iterating over your split Const, but just dynamically builds the control name.  Are the controls you're using ListBoxes?

Comment: yes, `Const cstrNames As String = "Listbox2,Listbox3,Listbox4,Listbox5,Listbox6,Listbox7,Listbox8,Listbox9,Listbox10,Listbox11,Listbox12,Listbox13"
`

Comment: @user3781528 - Are the actual controls on the form ListBoxes? Try `Dim current As Object`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Comment: Yes,  tried Dim current as object. Thank you so much, it would take me forever to figure this out.

Comment: is it possible to enable shift select in a listbox to select a range of items?

Comment: @user3781528 - `ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended`